# AngularJS Service for XHR

Tags: javascript, api, angularjs, jsonp, reddit

I am trying to create a service in AngularJS which would fetch me JSON data from a website.
I wrapped the service in a factory method as shown below

```
App.factory('httpService', function($http) {
    delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    return {
        getData : function() {
            var url = "http://www.reddit.com/.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
            return $http.jsonp(url).then(
                function(result) {
                    return result;
                });
        }
    }
});
```

The problem I'm coming across is that I receive an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`. When I use `get()` instead of `json()` I get a `501`/CORS error.

The URLs from where I am trying to fetch the data are: 
http://api.4chan.org/b/1.json
http://www.reddit.com/.json

following is a link to my jsfiddle with the rest of the code.

http://jsfiddle.net/fatgamer85/adPue/3/

Does any one has any idea on how to solve this?

**EDIT: I have managed to get the data and solved the issue. Thanks to sza**

Following is the code which I've used if anyone's interested

```
var myApp = angular.module("client", []);

myApp.factory('myXHRService', function($http) {
    delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    return {
        getData : function(url) {
            return $http.jsonp(url).then(
                function(result) {
                    return result.data;
                }
            );
        }
    }
});

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, myXHRService) {
    $scope.xhrData = {};
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.url = "http://www.reddit.com/.json?jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK";
    myXHRService.getData($scope.url).then(function(data) {
        var xhrData = angular.fromJson(data);
        $scope.xhrData = xhrData.data.children;
    });
});

myApp.config(function($httpProvider){
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
});
```

The main difference here is the callback in URL parameters `jsonp` apart from that, everything works fine and dandy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may relate to API endpoint issue of Reddit.com. If you try this API, it will work using jsonp

```
var url = "http://www.reddit.com/top.json?jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK";
```

For the API `/.json`, I suggest you implement the server side code to retrieve data though it returns valid JSON but somehow can't be accessed correctly across domain.

Comment: that solves the issue with reddit, but that wouldn't make my service  generic wouldn't it?

I can solve the issue in jQuery by requesting with jsonp headers, but the same trick won't work in angular; Not sure why.

Do you know how to make the service generic so that I could use the same service to request from different URLs?